# TextOutput not working in shiny R

Tags: r, text, shiny

I have a shiny app that I would like to display a text in the main panel. But it seem that the TextOutput does not work. Is there a way to put a space line in between tables?  Here is the code. Thank you for your time

```
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("amountTable", "Amount Tables", 1:10),
      actionButton("submit1" ,"Submit", icon("refresh"),
                class = "btn btn-primary"),

      actionButton("refresh1" ,"Refresh", icon("refresh"),
                class = "btn btn-primary")

     ),
   mainPanel(
   # UI output
    uiOutput("dt")
   )
  )
 )

 server <-  function(input, output, session) {

  global <- reactiveValues(refresh = FALSE)

  observe({
    if(input$refresh1) isolate(global$refresh <- TRUE)
  })

  observe({
    if(input$submit1) isolate(global$refresh <- FALSE)
  })

  observeEvent(input$submit1, {
    lapply(1:input$amountTable, function(amtTable) {
    output[[paste0('T', amtTable)]] <- DT::renderDataTable({
      iris[1:amtTable, ]
    })
  })
})

observe({
  lapply(1:input$amountTable, function(j) {
    output[[paste0('Text', j)]] <- renderText({
      paste0("This is AmountTable", j)
      br()  ## add space in between the text and table
    })
  })
})

output$dt <- renderUI({  
   if(global$refresh) return()
    tagList(lapply(1:10, function(i) {
      textOutput(paste0('Text', i))
      dataTableOutput(paste0('T', i))
    }))
})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attached code works for me.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("amountTable", "Amount Tables", 1:10),
      actionButton("submit1" ,"Submit", icon("refresh"),
                class = "btn btn-primary"),

      actionButton("refresh1" ,"Refresh", icon("refresh"),
                class = "btn btn-primary")

     ),
   mainPanel(
   # UI output
    uiOutput("dt")
   )
  )
 )

 server <-  function(input, output, session) {

  global <- reactiveValues(refresh = FALSE)

  observe({
    if(input$refresh1) isolate(global$refresh <- TRUE)
  })

  observe({
    if(input$submit1) isolate(global$refresh <- FALSE)
  })

  observeEvent(input$submit1, {
    lapply(1:input$amountTable, function(amtTable) {
    output[[paste0('T', amtTable)]] <- DT::renderDataTable({
      iris[1:amtTable, ]
    })
  })
})

observeEvent(input$submit1, {

  lapply(1:input$amountTable, function(j) {
    output[[paste0('Text', j)]] <- renderText({
      paste0("This is AmountTable", j)
      # br()  ## add space in between the text and table
    })
  })
})

output$dt <- renderUI({  
   if(global$refresh) return()
    tagList(lapply(1:input$amountTable, function(i) {
      list(textOutput(paste0('Text', i)),br(),
      dataTableOutput(paste0('T', i)))
    }))
})


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please let me know it it resolve your issue.